# Replacing links around image tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string

I have a string (in Wordpress) with HTML content and I want to replace every link URL around an image tag with another URL:

```
Before: <a href="A"><img src="X"></a>
After: <a href="B"><img src="X"></a>
```

First I wanted to do it with regular expressions, but then I read that this not recommended at all. So is there a possibility to do this with PHP?

Comment: Yes, [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DOM API

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlString, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
// the flags are for if you're not using a complete document, ie an HTML fragment
// You'll need the libxml extension enabled

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// find all <a> tags with an "href" attribute and <img> child element
$links = $xpath->query('//a[@href and img]');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->setAttribute('href', 'B');
}
$newHtmlString = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/ZHTYG

Comment: Thank you, this is phantastic! The flags didn't work (variable became empty) so I had to add encoding, otherwise special characters were converted wrong: `$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));`. I didn't find the query syntax in the php documentation, is there sth official where I can look it up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily with **DOMDocument** :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<a href="A"><img src="X"></a>');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) {
    $item->setAttribute('href', 'B');
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: This will change **all** links, whether they contain an image or not. Also, you're only ever changing the first link as your `exit` is inside the loop